# Data Security Profile (Alias Transitions)

Tags: business-objects

My universe in development uses development database (prefix 'D_').
I have one universe in Integration environment.
This is for end-user's tests. A new version of the universe is just copied to the Integation env from development env.

The universe in the Integration env has ti use another database (prefix 'I_').
I tried to solve this by defining a data security profile on the universe in the Integration env. (I defined profile, and on 'Tables' tab I defined the corresponding tables).

The thing is - it is functioning as expected for tables, but not for aliases. Moreover, when I try to insert the new 'tranisition' from D_ table to the corresponding I_ table, I click on 'INSERT', but no ALIAS tables are shown.

QUESTION: How to define these 'transitions' from D_ to I_ alias tables?

Answer (score 0):

We can only replace the universe tables by the database table by using security profile. I don't have much idea about new option table qualifiers.

Have you checked the option "change table qualifiers and owners which is there in data foundation while doing the right click on a  table.

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: Not sure we are on the same page. When I am developing a universe I use development databse as basis for data foundation layer. This universe is published in DEV folder on the server. Beside DEV I have also creater INT folder. In this folder I publish the latest stable version, so that the end user can test the new features without influencing on DEV universe. In the same matter I have created PROD folder for productive universe. Of course universe in INT folder uses INT database, and the universe in PROD folder uses PROD universe. In sum - 3 different folder, 3 universes, 3 databases

Comment: So the initial problem was - since I am developing by taking DEV database as a basis for the data foundation layer in, how can I update the universes in INT and PROD folders. From this forum I got recommendation, that the best practice would be to use data security profile and define 'transition' tables. So for example, if DEV Universe uses the table 'D_Table_1', for a universe in INT folder inside the data security profile I define transition 'D_Table_1' -> 'I_Table_1'. And that is working ok. Problem is with aliases. I can't define these transitions for alias tables.

Comment: Therefore, 2 questions arise: (1) is the approach with data security profiles and the definition of transitions the right one? (with the structure DEV, INT, PROD folders for different environments and different universes, with different databases). (2) if yes, how to configure the universe in INT folder to use aliases in a correct manner? Alias in INT universe should take 'I_' database, rather than 'D_' database.